# Knockout JS - update ViewModel data by custom script

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel

I would like to implement knockout functionality to an already existing page. Therefore I want to manipulate with the ViewModel data from existing script. I have mocked up an example but it doesn't work correctly.

A ViewModel is correctly bound to the UI (*try typing in the input*). It functions also when I modify the ViewModel data in backend (*by pressing a button*). However when I modify the input value again by typing into the input box, the data is not changed.

How can I propperly modify ViewModel data from backend (*some existing code manipulates the data*). Please note, that I have used jQuery click event as an example. Existing code may manipulate the data in the different manner.

Here is the code (HTML):

```xml
<!-- View -->
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: myName"></strong></p>
<input data-bind="value: myName"></input>
<button>Click me</button>
```

And JS:

```cs
// ViewModel
var AppViewModel = function() {
    this.myName= ko.observable("John Doe");
}
// ViewModel instance
var app = new AppViewModel();

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(app);

// Custom external code that changes the data in the ViewModel instance
$("button").click(function() {
    app.myName= ko.observable("Steve Peterson");
    ko.applyBindings(app);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating new observable in click handler

```
app.myName= ko.observable("Steve Peterson");
```

modify value of existing observable

```
app.myName("Steve Peterson");
```

Working example
http://jsfiddle.net/S9HBq/